# Using NULL in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

(Note: I'm not asking how to compare a column with `NULL`.)

I notice that in PostgreSQL if we do `SELECT 42 WHERE NULL`, the result set is empty. Therefore, something like `SELECT c FROM t WHERE c > 0` will select all rows from `t` where `c` is **both not `NULL` and greater than zero** (because when `c` is `NULL` the condition `c > 0` evaluates to `NULL`).

What I'm not sure is whether I can rely on this behavior, because `WHERE NULL` seems like a hack. (Probably the more proper way is using a `CASE` expression.)

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT c FROM t WHERE c is null`?

Comment: @YuvalPruss I need `c` to be both not `NULL` and greater than zero though.

Comment: So: `SELECT c FROM t WHERE c is null or c > 0`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Comparisons_with_NULL_and_the_three-valued_logic_.283VL.29

Comment: @YuvalPruss That would return rows where `c` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not Postgres-specific behavior.  It is how SQL is defined and how `NULL` values are defined in SQL.

The condition:

```
WHERE c > 0
```

is an *affirmative* condition.  It keeps all rows where `c > 0` evaluates to true.

When `c` is `NULL`, then `c > 0` evaluates to `NULL`.  `NULL` is not true (neither is it false), so `c > 0` filters out `NULL` values.  Almost all comparisons to `NULL` return `NULL`.

In addition:

```
WHERE NOT (c > 0)
```

also filters out `NULL` values, because `NOT NULL` is the same as `NULL`.

If you want to keep `NULL` values, I would recommend being explicit:

```
WHERE c > 0 OR c IS NULL
```

Comment: Ah I see, so when doing boolean computation `NULL` is basically an unknown that makes some of the results also unknowns. But `TRUE OR ...` and `FALSE AND ...` always have deterministic results whatever the other predicates evaluate to.

Comment: And, `SELECT` keeps only the `TRUE` rows, and throws away both the `FALSE` and unknown rows...right?

Answer (score 2):

According to my interpretation of [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html) you can rely on the fact that only non-null elements will be returned:

> Ordinary comparison operators yield null (signifying "unknown"), not true or false, when either input is null. For example, 7 = NULL yields null, as does 7 <> NULL. When this behavior is not suitable, use the IS [ NOT ] DISTINCT FROM predicates:

```
a IS DISTINCT FROM b
a IS NOT DISTINCT FROM b
```

> For non-null inputs, IS DISTINCT FROM is the same as the <> operator. However, if both inputs are null it returns false, and if only one input is null it returns true. Similarly, IS NOT DISTINCT FROM is identical to = for non-null inputs, but it returns true when both inputs are null, and false when only one input is null. Thus, these predicates effectively act as though null were a normal data value, rather than "unknown".
>
> To check whether a value is or is not null, use the predicates:

```
expression IS NULL
expression IS NOT NULL
```

> or the equivalent, but nonstandard, predicates:

```
expression ISNULL
expression NOTNULL
```

> Do not write expression = NULL because NULL is not "equal to" NULL. (The null value represents an unknown value, and it is not known whether two unknown values are equal.)